# Driver not installed error when running powershell add-OdbcDsn

Tags: powershell, odbc

Problem is add-odbcdsn is returning "driver not installed error" ,  though I can create using the GUI. Below is a piece from my code that returns the error. I also tried to create an ODBC connection using the GUI and specifying  the driver. I then do get-odbcdsn for that DSN. Use the output for that and run add-odbcdsn. This action also results in a driver not installed error.

```
$dsn_object = @{
    Name =  "123"
    DriverName = "C:\app\oracle64\product\12.2.0\client64\BIN\SQORA32.DLL"
    DsnType = "System"
    Platform = "64-bit"
    SetPropertyValue = ""
}

$dsn_values = -split @"
DisableRULEHint=T
Attributes=W
SQLTranslateErrors=F
AggregateSQLType=FLOAT
MaxTokenSize=8192
FetchBufferSize=64000
NumericSetting=NLS
ForceWCHAR=F
FailoverDelay=10
FailoverRetryCount=10
MetadataIdDefault=F
BindAsFLOAT=F
BindAsDATE=F
CloseCursor=F
EXECSchemaOpt=
EXECSyntax=F
Application Attributes=T
QueryTimeout=T
CacheBufferSize=20
StatementCache=F
ResultSets=T
MaxLargeData=0
UseOCIDescribeAny=F
Failover=T
Lobs=T
DisableMTS=T
DisableDPM=F
BatchAutocommitMode=IfAllSuccessful
Description=64 Bit TEST Oracle
ServerName=
Password=
UserID=homersimpson
DSN=64 Bit TEST Oracle
"@

$dsn_object.SetPropertyValue = $dsn_values
Add-OdbcDsn @dsn_object
```

I have also tried a simple example:

```
add-OdbcDsn -Name "TEST" -DriverName "C:\app\oracle64\product\12.2.0 \client64\BIN\SQORA32.DLL" -DsnType System
```

Expect the DSN to be created...

```
Add-OdbcDsn : The driver {C:\app\oracle64\product\12.2.0\client64\BIN\SQORA32.DLL} is not installed.

Get-OdbcDriver shows the driver is there:
```

Name
Value
----                           -----
APILevel                       1
FileUsage                      0
Driver                         C:\app\oracle64\product\12.2.0\client64\BIN\SQORA32.DLL
ConnectFunctions               YYY
CPTimeout                      60
DriverODBCVer                  03.51
SQLLevel                       1
Setup                          C:\app\oracle64\product\12.2.0\client64\BIN\SQORAS32.DLL

Answer (score 1):

After all that, I resolved it. I realized I was using the path to the driver as the name and not the actual name as seen in the ODBC GUI.